# Firebase cloud messege on Opera

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, opera

I have a problem with FCM on Opera browser. Exactly with token register. 
On Chrome and Firefox all works fine.

- Step 1: On Opera allow permissions to push notification.
- Step 2: Send by Curl message to FCM.
- Step 3: Message received.
- Step 4: turn off browser. (don't work in background)
- Step 5: turn on browser.
- Step 6: Send by Curl message (the same token as before)
- Step 7: don't receive a message.

Problem is when I turn off browser and turn on again browser has a diffrent token. On another browser I haven't this problem. Always I have the same FCM token.

I use: firebase 4.8.1
Opera: 50.0.2762.45